# If I have use ovs 2.16.1， which version of ovn should I install？

Tags: c++, c, version, sdn, openvswitch

I couldn't find a version mapping between OVN (Open Virtual Network) and OVS (OpenvSwitch) on the official website of OVN and OVS. Now, if I have installed OVS 2.16.1 in ubuntu 20.04, which version of OVN should I install？